# Use structured data script with Content Security Policy header

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm using CSP headers to protect my website with maximum security (using nonces in both script-src and style-src options).
I'm also using a valid structured data script with script HTML tag in such a way:
`<script type="application/ld+json" nonce="NONCE_VALUE">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type": "Organization",[etc...]</script>`

However, chrome developer tools reports of style-src violations and requires to add hashes in style-src-elem:

`Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src-attr 'self' 'report-sample' 'nonce-NONCE_VALUE'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-HASH_VALUE'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.`

I don't want to add those hashes to my CSP header, it doesn't make sense to me since I add nonces both to script-src and style-src (style-src-attr in my specific exemple). I actually do not understand why the script, despite have a nonce, is requesting an extra option for the style elements.
What should be the correct way to use structured datas with CSP headers?